# .py file interact with .kv file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

So i have created some screens and added some properties to them (layouts, buttons, name etc) but everything is on the kivy file. Now, i want to make a function in the python main file which will take me from the starting screen to the next one after a brief time. Though nothing seems to work without me having to move everything from the kivy file to the python file. Any ideas?

.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass


class AndAnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class BackgroundLabel(Label):
    pass

class CompanyImage(Image):
    pass

class LoadingScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoadingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def ChangeScreen(self):
        ScreenManager().current = MainScreen().name



presentation = Builder.load_file("tsalapp.kv")


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

.kv

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock
#: import Color kivy.graphics
#: import Rectangle kivy.graphics

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    LoadingScreen:
    MainScreen:
    AnotherScreen:
    AndAnotherScreen:

<BackgroundLabel>:
    background_color: 30,144,255,1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<LoadingScreen>:
    name: "main"
    id: "yolo"
    on_enter: Clock.schedule_once(none, 3)
    #app.root.current: "menu"
    Image:
        source: 'Untitled.png'
        height: root.height
        width: root.width
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
    AnchorLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Tsala Inc."
            anchor_x: 'center'
            anchor_y: 'center'
            font_size: root.height/15





<MainScreen>:
    name: "menu"
    id: "swag"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: "Next Page"
            background_color: 1,1,4,1
            size_hint: (0.5, 0.5)
            on_release:
                app.root.current= "Another Screen"
        Button:
            text: "Previous Page"
            background_color: 1,4,1,1
            size_hint: (0.5, 0.5)
            on_release:
                app.root.current= "And Another Screen"

<AnotherScreen>:
    name: "Another Screen"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Button:
            text: "Previous Page"
            background_color: 0,0,1,1
            size_hint: (0.25,1)
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "menu"
        Button:
            text: "Exit"
            background_color: 1,0,0,1
            size_hint: (0.25, 1)
            on_release:
                exit()

<AndAnotherScreen>:
    name: "And Another Screen"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: "Next Page"
            background_color: 1,1,4,1
            size_hint: (0.5, 0.5)
            on_release:
                app.root.current= "menu"
        Button:
            text: "Nextest Page"
            background_color: 1,4,1,1
            size_hint: (0.5, 0.5)
            on_release:
                app.root.current= "Another Screen"
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I recommend create a global variable for screenmanager or place screenmanager in the MainApp as class property and create a list or a dictionary for the screens:

```
class MyApp(App):

    sm = ScreenManager() # screenmanager
    screens = {} # dictionary for the screens, I prefer dictionary because string indexes are more convenient
```

Then in a build method you can create all screens you need and return the screenmanager as root widget:

```
class MyApp(App):

    sm = ScreenManager() # screenmanager
    screens = {} # dictionary for the screens, I prefer dictionary because string indexes are more convenient

    def build(self):
        self.__create_screens()
        MyApp.sm.add_widget(MyApp.screens['main_screen'])
        return MyApp.sm

    def __create_screens(self):
        MyApp.screens['main_screen'] = MainScreen(name='mainscreen')
        MyApp.screens['another_screen'] = AnotherScreen(name='another_screen')
        MyApp.screens['and_another_screen'] = AndAnotherScreen(name='and_another_screen')
```

So now you can switch your app's screens easily wherever you want using [switch_to](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.switch_to) method:

```
MyApp.sm.switch_to(MyApp.screens['another_screen'], direction='left', duration=1)
```

Comment: I tried it but it still doesnt seem to work, i still would have to move everything from the kv file into the python file which is what i want to avoid as the code becomes pretty weird. Thank you for your time though

Comment: @tsalamagewski try to return screenmanager on build (see update).